# Scale Interior While Retaining Objects Scale

Tags: transforms

I was wondering if there was a way to take the object in the first picture and increase its interior radius, without scaling the actual rectangles scales.

1x1x2 Blocks

[image: 1x1x2]

1x1x6 Blocks

[image: 1x1x6]

Comment: Well not without modifiers at least. If those blocks were made using the solidify modifier you could scale them at will in edit mode. Otherwise use the top view and move the vertex 2 units in X or Y direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want to use the scale command you can only do it using modifiers to add thickness, otherwise the scale command will also affect the thickness of the blocks.

[image: Resize Solidify]

Otherwise use the move command instead and move the vertex 2 units in X or Y.

[image: Move vertex]

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you for the quick reply